# Agora.io Flexible Classroom roleType and Chat errors

Tags: javascript, sdk, agora.io, chatroom, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have few issues regarding the use of flexible classroom sdk version:
https://download.agora.io/edu-apaas/release/edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js

1. Facing the following error when i change the "roleType", Currently only option 4 is working if i change it to 0 or 2, get following error:

   > Unknown error occured. Code: 30409104 Details: roomType conflict.
2. Chat is not working(either on teacher or student or anyone.

   > Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
   > at Object.parse ()
   > at edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:489:2135392
   > at r.handleKeyDown (edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:418:557191)
   > at Object.Fe (edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:465:16071)
   > at He (edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:465:16225)
   > at edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:465:34152
   > at Er (edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:465:34246)
   > at Ir (edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:465:34660)
   > at edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:465:40308
   > at Le (edu_sdk_1.1.5.10.js:465:116015)

My config is as follows:

```
AgoraEduSDK.config({
  // Here pass in the Agora App ID you have got
  appId: '',
})
AgoraEduSDK.launch(
  document.querySelector("#root1"), {
    // Here pass in the RTM token you have generated
    rtmToken: "",
    // The user ID must be the same as the one you used for generating the RTM token
    userUuid: "mynewt",


    userName: "Teacher",
    roomUuid: "abcdefgh",
    roomName: "demo-class",
    roleType: 1,
    roomType: 4,
    pretest: false,
    language: "en",
    startTime: new Date().getTime(),
    duration: 60 * 30,
    courseWareList: [],
    listener: (evt) => {
      console.log("personal events", evt)
    }
  }
)
```

Maybe some errors from the sdk built in. I need to resolve these 2 issues so that i can continue to implement it on my LMS.

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to support by opening a ticket - https://agora-ticket.agora.io/

Comment: @EkaanshArora alright i ll see that